# how to get Kendo grid row selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to enable kendo ui grid row selection .I created a kendo grid by using html helper function accessed it via javascript and enabled row selction ,but no luck code is shown below

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Gridkendo.Models.Model>)Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Name);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Description);
```

and accessed it in javascript

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Notice that the Name() of the grid is used to get its client-side instance
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        alert(selectedItem.ShipName);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Here is selection demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection here is ASP.MVC GridBuilder api: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/gridbuilder#methods-Selectable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `Selectable()` configuration method. This will enable the default row selection,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Gridkendo.Models.Model>)Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Name);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Description);
  })
  .Selectable()
)
```

**Note** that you are getting the selected item in the `document ready` event. This means that the grid has just been initialized and it's improbable that any row had been selected. A better approach is to use the "select" event, configurable in the helper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<Gridkendo.Models.Model>)Model)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      // Create a column bound to the ProductID property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Name);
      // Create a column bound to the ProductName property
      columns.Bound(product => product.Description);
  })
  .Selectable()
  .Events(ev => ev.Change("doOnRowSelect"))
)
```

You then need to define the `doOnRowSelect` JavaScript function:

```
function doOnRowSelect(e) {
    var selectedItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
    alert(selectedItem.ShipName);
}
```

**EDIT:** the method above (at least the JavaScript part) works only when the data is loaded trough AJAX. The row selection however should also work when the data is loaded from the `Model`. In this care, the selected row will have the `k-state-selected` class:

```
function getSelectedItem () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedRows = $(".k-state-selected", "#grid");
    if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
       var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
       alert(selectedItem.ShipName);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting exception like "There is no DataSource Model Id property specified"

Comment: @peter, yes, unfortunately getting the selected item does not work when populating the grid trough the `Model`. It only works with AJAX loading ([see here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem)). Remove the event then. Are you now able to select a table row?

Comment: still exception "There is no DataSource Model Id property specified." is getting